# iPhone "Cannot Play Movie - The server is not correctly configured"

Tags: iphone, ios, video-streaming, h.264, mp4

Everything I read on this error says I need to make sure that the server is accepting byte ranges.  However, it appears it is.  When I hit the mp4 directly in Chrome these are the headers:

Initial response headers:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:11268167
Content-Type:video/mp4
Date:Mon, 14 May 2012 23:33:53 GMT
ETag:W/"46044b-afe121-4c0076fd1068e"
Last-Modified:Mon, 14 May 2012 23:28:00 GMT
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Cnection:close
```

Request after that response is received (the bytes range request below looks odd):

```
Accept-Encoding:identity;q=1, *;q=0
Range:bytes=0-
Referer:http://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/videos/en-us/mobile/Manual-Calibration-ZT210_640X360-A.mp4
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19
```

Final response:

```
Connection:keep-alive, Transfer-Encoding
Content-Type:video/mp4
Date:Mon, 14 May 2012 23:33:53 GMT
ETag:W/"46044b-afe121-4c0076fd1068e"
Last-Modified:Mon, 14 May 2012 23:28:00 GMT
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Cnection:close
```

Here is a link to the mp4 file:  http://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/videos/en-us/mobile/Manual-Calibration-ZT210_640X360-A.mp4

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the gzip?  Isn't the video already compressed and thus shouldn't be returned as Transfer-Encoding: chunked?

Comment: This is actually being caused by our CDN Akamai.  Ughs...  This URL works:  http://orig-www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/videos/en-us/mobile/Manual-Calibration-ZT210_640X360-A.mp4    Any idea why?